# Modular arithmetic notation - meaning of multiple arguments - $y \pmod{a,b}$

Tags: number-theory, notation, modular-arithmetic, cryptography

I understand Modular arithmetic with one argument eg $y \pmod{a}$.

I have two questions re this notation with multiple arguments - what is the meaning of the following and how to calculate them:

1. $y \pmod{a,b}$ where $y$, $a$, $b$ are positive integers? Eg $14 \pmod{3, 7}$
2. $y \pmod{a,b}$ where $b$ is a positive integer, and $a$ and $y$ are different polynomials / Quotient rings? Eg $x^5+3 \pmod{x^2-1, 7}$

Eg in AKS primality test - Wikipedia:

> if $(X+a)^n≠ X^n+a \pmod {X^r − 1, n}$, output composite;

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/AKS_primality_test

Comment: It's not a standard notation. Can you tell where you have found it in use, and quote some examples with more context?

Comment: Have you read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AKS_primality_test#Concepts?

Comment: @gammatester - I realise it's used for polynomials (stated in question), but I don't know how to interpret the notation.

Comment: @henningmakholm question updated

Comment: @gammatester yes I have read it. But asking question since I don't understand it that well.

Comment: Compute the polynomial remainder $\bmod x^r-1$ and reduce the polynomial coefficients $\bmod n$

Comment: @gammatester Can you do it in in a different way - eg mod $n$ first, then mod $x^r-1$?

Answer (score 1):

You just needed to read ahead another couple of lines on the page in question
in order to find out what the notation means:

$$ (x+a)^{n}\equiv (x^{n}+a){\pmod {x^{r}-1,n}}$$

means

$$ (x+a)^{n}-(x^{n}+a)=(x^{r}-1)g+nf \quad \text{for some polynomials $f$ and $g.$}  $$

The explanation was probably thought to be necessary since this is not a typical notation.

Comment: Does this mean that one can do either: $mod n$ or polynomial division $mod x^r - n$ first?

Comment: That would depend on whether "first" is part of an algorithm that goes, "first this, then that, then done." For example, to show that $2x^3 + x + 3 \equiv 0 \pmod{x^2 - 1,3},$ if you take the remainders of the coefficients modulo $3$ first you get $2x^3 + x$, and division by $x^2 - 1$ then leaves a remainder of $3x.$ To show equivalence to zero, you have to take the remainder modulo $3$ again. So I think "mod $n$, then mod $x^r - 1$, then stop," does not work in general; but you can do "mod $n$, then mod $x^r - 1$, repeat until the remainder is unchanged."